# Extending confirmation emails Magento 2

Tags: php, email, magento2

I would like to add conditional text into my confirmation emails in magento 2. As in:

```
 {{if order contains item }}

 text

 {{else order doesnt contain item}}

 other text
```

At the moment I am aware that the email displays items with this:

```
{{layout handle="sales_email_order_items" order=$order area="frontend"}}
```

Is this configurable?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

For this purpose, i use an external phtml template :

- in the design area, create the module you want to modify, I your case, it's Magento_Sales
- in templates directory add /email/your-template.phtml :

```
Magento_Sales
    /email
       the-email-to-modify.html
    /templates
        /email
            your-template.phtml
```

In your-template.phtml, use php as usuale

```
<?php
//your code, with the test
// to get the variables use:
$myvar=$this->getData('myvar');
...?>
<p>Hello <?php echo $myvar; ?></p>
```

In the HTML template the-email-to-modify.html, you can include your template and send any variables you want, here the customer name :

```
<h1>The title</h1>
{{block class='Magento\\Framework\\View\\Element\\Template' 
    myvar=$customer.name area='frontend' 
    template='Magento_Sales::email/your-template.phtml'}}
```

et voila ^^